# free electron laser. Reference?

Tags: specific-reference, synchrotron-radiation, free-electron-lasers

Where can I find a comparison graph of the peak power of free electron lasers and synchrotrons ?

Comment: Did you try google image search

Comment: I have downloaded the image year ago but would prefer the source, the paper.

Comment: I meant https://images.google.com/. You can upload the image and search, adding a couple of keywords I usually was able to find the original articles.

Comment: @Anonymous, is my answer helpful to you, or no?

Comment: Thanks it is helpful but there isnt peak power data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A similar graph is shown in chapter four, on page 76, of *Controlling the Quantum World: The Science of Atoms, Molecules, and Photons* (you can read it online [here](https://www.nap.edu/read/11705/chapter/6)):

[image]

The other similar graph I found is at [this page](http://cerncourier.com/cws/article/cern/44357) on the CERN website:

[image]

I'll keep searching.